# Loading resources dynamically with a link or script tag for google chart allowed?

Tags: appexchange, static-resources, security-review, google-charts

Our App did not pass the App Exchange security review because of the following issue

> JS not in Static Resource

For jquery and datatables there is a officially accepted source file to load data into static resource but in case of **google chart** there is no option for it.

https://www.google.com/jsapi

In that case, will security review team accept us to refer the link directly?Need suggestions

Thanks